# How to connect to SQL Server(VM) from local docker instance on MAC

Tags: sql-server, docker

I have got a SQL Server docker instance up and running.

I am able to connect to my local DB and create tables as well.

How do I connect to a database instance (VM) outside of my local setup using Docker?

Comment: Where is the database running: on the host itself or another system?  If it's another system, you shouldn't need to do anything special and your existing configuration should work; if it's the host, [From inside of a Docker container, how do I connect to the \[host\] machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach) has the standard recipe.

Comment: SQL DB is hosted on another server , I am trying to connect to the server instance from local Docker container

Comment: What specific problem are you having?  Can you edit the question to include a [mcve] demonstrating it?